# Relational DB design: connecting different kind of "objects"

Tags: database, relational

I am currently designing a Database for a Project of mine. The target is to connect different kind of "Objects" like Web-links, text, pictures and files with each other.
Using the following tables my first attempt ended as described below:

```
TABLE text
TABLE picture
TABLE file
```

so my first attempt was to connect each Table to the Table "Project" by using n:m relations. after that I  had to create a Table which safes the connections between those objects, so I created a "relation" Table. But then the Problem appeared, that I am not able to connect each table (text,picture and file) to each other very efficiently.

Does anyone of you guys now how to do such a thing in a good way?
Thanks for your help in advance!
CyrillC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`N:M relation` can be resolved using the following technique. Lets suppose there is an entity `Student`, you create a table named `Student`, an entity `Teacher` so a table `Teacher` is created. Lets suppose `one teacher` can teach `many` `students` and `one student` can be taught by `many teachers`. So, to resolve this so can introduce `weak entity`, lets suppose you create a table named `TeacherStudent`. The columns of `TeacherStudent` could be `pkTeacherStudentId`, `fkTeacherId`, `fkStudentId`.

The same approach could be applied in your case to resolve `N:M` relation.

Hope this help.

Comment: not really, I already now how to create n:m relations. my problem is that I don't want to use three "weak entitys" like "textPicture","textFile" and "PictureFile". I am rather searching for a better solution, if there is any. Best would be to have one single "relation" entity..

Comment: I now changed it to one "object" Table which has a n:m relation to itself. The Entity has a media attribute which determines its content attribute.